# Tracing to Original Source Code for JQuery attached functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One benefit of calling functions directly from markup is that it is easier to track what's being called. I would like to know if there is an browser addon or something that supports a  "Goto javascript source function" for each of the events attached (bound) to an element. Ideally this would take me to the original location it got bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FireQuery add on with Firefox browser. It will show you all the events attached to a dom element.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Chrome 12 debugger will show you any Event Listeners for any object in the DOM.  It can be quite useful, especially to find your way around a larger project.  It shows you what event and where the code is.